# no entiendo los nombres y las sentencia

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Buenas estoy leyendo lo apuntes que tengo muy malos por cierto y tengo un ejemplpo

```
create or replace procedure alta_emp
    (v_emp_no in emp.empno%TYPE,
    v_emp_name in emp.ename%TYPE,
    v_emp_job in emp.job%TYPE,
    v_mgr_no in emp.mgr%type,
    v_emp_sal emp.sal%type)
is
    v_emp_hiredate emp.hiredate%type;
    v_emp_comm emp.comm%type;
    v_emp_deptno emp.deptno%type;
begin
    v_emp_hiredate:=sysdate;
    v_emp_comm:=0;
    select deptno into v_emp_depno from emp where empno = v_mgr_no;
    insert into ..
```

duda 1 porque v_emp_no y name es in emp.e loquesea y las demas no llevan e

duda 2 porqye v_emp_sal no lleva in

duda 3 puedo poner fecha_cont envez de hiredate o tiene que ser en ingles por narice

duda 4 porque mgr_no  no es v_emp_mgrn

duda 5 que es comm

este es el scrip de creacion de tablas por si os ayuda https://www.dropbox.com/s/mw3nl43neli9722/CreaEmpScott.sql?dl=0
muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*duda 1 porque v_emp_no y name es in emp.e loquesea y las demas no llevan e?* Porque así crearon las tablas. Los parámetros se están definiendo como "del mismo tipo de la columna empno de la tabla emp". Culpa al que definió los nombres de las columnas de la tabla.

*duda 2 porqye v_emp_sal no lleva in?* Porque las variables en la firma del método que dicen IN son variables de entrada, sólo reciben parámetros. Las que digan OUT son sólo de salida. Las que no tienen nada son de entrada Y salida.

*duda 3 puedo poner fecha_cont envez de hiredate o tiene que ser en ingles por narice?* Puedes poner el nombre que quieras; es una variable interna del método y en general no le importa el idioma mientras no uses tildes, eñes, etc.

*duda 4 porque mgr_no no es v_emp_mgrn?* Habrá que preguntarle al que lo escribió. No hay una razón técnica para ello.

*duda 5 que es comm?* Una variable numérica que comienza en cero. Hasta ahí lo que se puede ver.

Y el script que pones en el enlace no tiene la tabla que usas en el procedimiento, así que no ayuda mucho.

Comment: pues esa es el scrip que tengo voy pregunta a compañero pero ese es el que me han ducho que se usa

Comment: perdonya he encontrado el link https://www.dropbox.com/s/mw3nl43neli9722/CreaEmpScott.sql?dl=0